# Using md5sum and date to update files with cp

Tags: linux, cp, md5

I use `cp -up --backup=t` to copy files from my computer to the cloud and reverse, but sometimes the date changes for a few minutes (or I guess even seconds, as I see the same file date stamp) as I compare the copied file and the backup one. Comparing the md5 hash number of both files they are the same. So my question is if it's possible for each file, that in case that the date of the file to copy is newer that the date of the file in the destination, check first if the md5 hash number is different, before making the copy, and if both have the same number, not to copy the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rsync` with the `-c` flag (`--checksum`), which compares files by checksum rather than by modification time and size.

### Example

```
root@node51 [/tmp]# mkdir source
root@node51 [/tmp]# mkdir destination
root@node51 [/tmp]# echo "version 1" > source/file.txt
root@node51 [/tmp]# sleep 1
root@node51 [/tmp]# echo "version 1" > destination/file.txt
```

Notice that I created two identical files at two different times, but their checksums are identical:

```
root@node51 [/tmp]# md5sum */file.txt
81127ad129dd2249f5ab0667ca0aeb84  destination/file.txt
81127ad129dd2249f5ab0667ca0aeb84  source/file.txt
root@node51 [/tmp]# stat */file.txt
  File: 'destination/file.txt'
  Size: 10          Blocks: 1          IO Block: 512    regular file
Device: 15h/21d Inode: 674358      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2016-08-10 13:14:12.710354355 -0500
Modify: 2016-08-10 13:14:12.710354355 -0500
Change: 2016-08-10 13:14:12.710354355 -0500
 Birth: -
  File: 'source/file.txt'
  Size: 10          Blocks: 1          IO Block: 512    regular file
Device: 15h/21d Inode: 674234      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2016-08-10 13:14:07.198447196 -0500
Modify: 2016-08-10 13:14:07.198447196 -0500
Change: 2016-08-10 13:14:07.198447196 -0500
 Birth: -
```

Using `rsync -avcP`:

```
root@node51 [/tmp]# touch source/file.txt
root@node51 [/tmp]# rsync -avcP source/ destination/
sending incremental file list
./

sent 87 bytes  received 22 bytes  218.00 bytes/sec
total size is 10  speedup is 0.09
```

The file was not copied.

A different run, using `rsync -avP`:

```
root@node51 [/tmp]# touch source/file.txt
root@node51 [/tmp]# rsync -avP source/ destination/
sending incremental file list
file.txt
             10 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/2)

sent 123 bytes  received 35 bytes  316.00 bytes/sec
total size is 10  speedup is 0.06
```

The file was copied.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I add -u to the options. -u was mandatory because it will copy an older file over a new one if they have different md5 hash number. My first "but" is with the speed. I use a webdav drive, and it's notably slower than cp. The other problem is that, I don't know why, it doesn't preserve the time stamp if I used the command in a makefile. The command is: rsync -v -u -c -P -a. But the time stamp is preserved If I used it directly. Anyway, it doesn't matter, but it just freaks me out.